# c++ compile error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer : else if

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I'm trying to print the output, but my code keep getting an error:

> C++ compile error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

The error is in `else if`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char BT [5][100];

    for (int i = 1; i<=2; i++){
        printf("\nInsert book title:");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &BT[i]);
        getchar ();
    }

    printf("\nOur Collections :\n"); 
    
    for (int i = 1; i<= 2 ; i++){   
        for (int i = 0; i< strlen(BT[i]); i++){
            int k;
            if ( i == 0 && BT[i][k] != ' ') {
                printf("Shelf code : %c\n", BT[i][k]);
            }
            else if ( i > 0 && BT[i - 1] == ' ') {
                printf("Shelf code : %c\n", BT[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about C, or C++?  Your title says one thing, but your tags say another.

Comment: The code is more C than C++ but your errors claim it is C++.  I'm not convinced that removing the C++ tag was appropriate.

Comment: You have a test `BT[i][k] != ' '` which is fine, but then you have another test `BT[i - 1] == ' '` which is not so fine.  "One of these things is not like the other." :-)

Comment: In fact, you are asking no question ! Please improve. By the way, as is often the case, the error message is a good hint.

Comment: I'm using dev c++ and c language

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  It's best to think of them that way.  Your compiler thinks you're using the C++ language.  That's not causing a problem today, but it will probably start causing problems tomorrow.  Try saving your code in a file ending in `.c`, or finding a language setting for "C" as opposed to "C++", or whatever it takes.

Comment: Tip: Creating a [mre] is always a helpful process!

Answer (score 2):

There are many mistakes.

For example indices in C for arrays start from `0` but you are using for loops where indices start from `1` like

```
for (int i = 1; i<=2; i++){
```

and below in the code you are trying to access `BT[0]`.

Or the function `scanf` for reading a string expects an argument of the type `char *` but you are passing an argument of the type `char ( * )[100]`.

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &BT[i]);
```

At least you should write

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", BT[i]);
```

Another problem is that you are using the uninitialized variable `k` to access elements of the array

```
        int k;
    if ( i == 0 && BT[i][k] != ' ') {
```

Moreover due to the fact the the element `BT[0]` does not have a value the condition in the if statement when `i` is equal to `0` invokes undefined behavior along with the uninitialized variable `k`.

Also it is a bad idea to use the same identifier `i` in the nested loops

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 2 ; i++){   
for (int i = 0; i< strlen(BT[i]); i++){
```

It seems you mean

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 2 ; i++){   
for (int k = 0; k< strlen(BT[i]); k++){
```

In this if statement

```
else if ( i > 0 && BT[i - 1] == ' ') {
```

the expression `BT[i-1]` has the type `char *`. So you are trying to compare a value of the type `char` with a value of the type `char *`.  You forgot to specify the second index for the array `BT`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You compile C program using C++ compiler which is wrong.
2. `BT[i - 1]` is an char array acting as lvalue (pointer) not character. You compare it to an integer `' '`. Even in C it will raise a warning and it is definitely not what you want.